# Convert <select> into <ul>, but keep functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert "select" into "ul" list to be able to style it nicely. The way it works in my plugin, is when you select one of the "select" options you get another section loaded below it. So, I have managed to convert "select" into "ul" using jQuery, but when I click on an option from "li" list it doesn't load my content as per original "select" dropdown.

Is there a way to do it? I guess it's something to do with values?

Below is my code:

```
$(".jr-form-categories").append('<ul id="property-list"></ul>');
$(".jr-cat-select option").each(function(){
    $("#property-list").append('<li><a href="' + $(this).attr('value') + '">' +     $(this).html() + '</a></li>');
});
$("#property-list").on("click", "li a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".jr-cat-select").val($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Here is HTML:

```
<select name="data[Listing][catid][]" class="jr-cat-select jrSelect" size="1">
    <option value="0">- Select Category -</option>
    <option value="4"> Flat</option>
    <option value="5"> House</option>
    <option value="7"> Shared Flat</option>   
    <option value="6"> Shared House</option>
    <option value="8"> Studio</option>  
</select>
```

And this is how the converted list looks like, which doesn't work when you click on of the links:

```
<ul id="property-list">
    <li><a href="0">- Select Category -</a></li>
    <li><a href="4"> Flat</a></li>
    <li><a href="5"> House</a></li>
    <li><a href="7"> Shared Flat</a></li>
    <li><a href="6"> Shared House</a></li>
    <li><a href="8"> Studio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's a nice plugin called [Select2](http://select2.github.io/).

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Which page you want it to go?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like [**Select2**](http://select2.github.io). This can convert your `<select>` into `<ul>` and `<li>` and not only that, it also gives you options like autosuggest and other things.

If you wanna convert it back, use `.select2("destroy")`. Very simple.

```js
$(function () {
  $("select").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select name="data[Listing][catid][]" class="jr-cat-select jrSelect" size="1">
  <option value="0">- Select Category -</option>
  <option value="4"> Flat</option>
  <option value="5"> House</option>
  <option value="7"> Shared Flat</option>   
  <option value="6"> Shared House</option>
  <option value="8"> Studio</option>  
</select>
```

A demonstration to convert it back to `<select>`:

```js
$(function () {
  $("select").select2();
  $("#remBtn").click(function () {
    $("select").select2("destroy");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select name="data[Listing][catid][]" class="jr-cat-select jrSelect" size="1">
  <option value="0">- Select Category -</option>
  <option value="4"> Flat</option>
  <option value="5"> House</option>
  <option value="7"> Shared Flat</option>   
  <option value="6"> Shared House</option>
  <option value="8"> Studio</option>  
</select>
<button id="remBtn">Remove</button>
```

Comment: @nnnnnn There's no element matching: `.jr-form-categories`

Comment: Obviously there is such an element, because the OP said that the UL is created. Presumably it's the form element containing the select. Clicking on the resulting li elements is the part that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar that looks like a nice plugin. However, I want to use list in a slightly different way. I want to transform those select options into 5 boxes with images/text, which you can select. Can you achieve it with this plugin? Here is simple example of what I want it to be: http://prntscr.com/bc68nc

Comment: @Vasiliy Everything is possible. Kindly have a look at the API please... :)